How to solve the circular import when declare parameter type of function?
This is my tokenizer file:

from framework.components.graph_to_text.utils import preprocess_text


class Tokenizer(object):

    def __init__(self,


But inside the utils file. I also have:
from framework.components.graph_to_text.tokenizer import Tokenizer


def greedy_search(probs: torch.Tensor,
                  list_oovs: List[str],
                  tokenizer: Tokenizer):


Just to declare the type of variable. How to avoid this?
Sorry i know my question is duplicated but I have no idea what they're talking:) to fix my case

You can e.g. place the from ... import preprocess_text only in the function(s) where you need preprocess_text.

awww I did think about this but in the other way around. Thank you
